# Problema con scanner en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-util-scanner

Buenas, estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto para trabajar con pacientes de hospital. Mi problema surge cuando quiero recibir datos por teclado.
¿Qué código tengo?

```
_       //Get nombre
        System.out.println("Introduzca nombre del paciente");
        Scanner name_scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        nombre=name_scanner.nextLine();
        name_scanner.close();

        //Get apellido 1
        System.out.println("Introduzca primer apellido del paciente");
        Scanner apell1_scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        apell1=apell1_scanner.nextLine();
        apell1_scanner.close();

        //Get apellido 2
        System.out.println("Introduzca segundo apellido del paciente");
        Scanner apell2_scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        apell2=apell2_scanner.nextLine();
        apell2_scanner.close();

        //Get edad
        System.out.println("Introduzca la edad del paciente");
        Scanner edad_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        edad=edad_scanner.nextInt();
        edad_scanner.close();

        //Get alcohol
        System.out.println("¿El paciente toma alcohol? Inserte Si - No");
        Scanner alcohol_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        alcohol= alcohol_scanner.nextLine();
        alcohol_scanner.close();

        //Get fumador
        System.out.println("¿El paciente fuma? Inserte Si - No");
        Scanner fumador_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        fumador= fumador_scanner.nextLine();
        fumador_scanner.close();

        //Get Numero Historial Clinico
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de historial clinico del              paciente");
        Scanner numhistorialclinico = new Scanner(System.in);
        num_historial_clinico=numhistorialclinico.nextInt();
        numhistorialclinico.close();

        //Get Diagnostico
        System.out.println("Introduzca observaciones/comentarios/diagnóstico del paciente");
        Scanner sc_diagnostico = new Scanner(System.in);
        diagnostico= sc_diagnostico.nextLine();
        sc_diagnostico.close();

        Paciente.RegisterPaciente(nombre, apell1, apell2, edad, alcohol,  fumador, num_historial_clinico, diagnostico);
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que me suelta el siguiente error:

```
_Por favor presione el número de la acción a realizar
 1 - Ingresar datos nuevo paciente
 2 - Consultar datos paciente
 3 - Eliminar paciente
 4 - Salir del programa
 1
 Introduzca nombre del paciente
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at MenuPacientes.getOption(MenuPacientes.java:46)
 at Main_Control_Pacientes.main(Main_Control_Pacientes.java:7)
```

Bueno pues este es el problema, que me imprime bien el menú, pulso 1 para registrar paciente, imprime lo de introducir el nombre, pero luego explota.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Cada escáner que uso lo abro, lo uso, y lo cierro. ¿Alguna ayuda pls?

Comment: Cual es el proposito de la llamada .close(), segundo, como lo hiciste para la primera pantalla, donde te requiere los primeros datos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema concreto es con tus llamadas a `.close()` con los scanners. Cada vez que ejecutas el `.close()` a un `Scanner`, esto también ejecuta `.close()` al `System.in`, lo que invalida tus demás scanners que intentan leer del `System.in`.

En realidad, parte del problema es que no hay razón de que crees una diferente instancia de `Scanner` cada vez que necesitas interactuar con el usuario. Solo necesitas una instancia de `Scanner` que puedes seguir usando a lo largo de tu programa (sin cerrarlo por supuesto).

Comment: su pregunta recomendacion es muy acertada, pero podria comentarle de que al usar el mismo `scanner` para leer datos numericos y despues string , *digo numericos pues deduzco que tambien toma estos datos para la seleccion en el menu*, y si sigue su recomendacion tiene que borrar el buffer, por ejemplo con `miScanner.nextLine();` antes de tomar el string, pues si antes obtuvo un dato numerico "se queda" en el buffer `\n` lo que puede provocar que no le funcione bien. Saludos

Comment: @sstan Ya sospechaba yo que era un problema de los `close()` no sabia que cerraran el system.in, pero ha quedado perfectamente claro con tu explicación.

Comment: @Keka Bron si se resolvio tu problema, marca como correcta esta respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que te comentó [sstan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18951/sstan) en su respuesta, no es recomendable de crear multitudes de `Scanner`.  Mientras manejas tu ingreso con solo un `Scanner` ten en cuenta que todos los métodos `nextXXX` aparte de `nextLine` no consumen el `"\\s"` que separa los datos:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Get nombre
    System.out.println("Introduzca nombre del paciente");
    nombre=scanner.nextLine();

    //Get apellido 1
    System.out.println("Introduzca primer apellido del paciente");
    apell1=scanner.nextLine();

    //Get apellido 2
    System.out.println("Introduzca segundo apellido del paciente");
    apell2=scanner.nextLine();

    //Get edad
    System.out.println("Introduzca la edad del paciente");
    edad=scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine(); // consumir \s

    //Get alcohol
    System.out.println("¿El paciente toma alcohol? Inserte Si - No");
    alcohol= scanner.nextLine();

    //Get fumador
    System.out.println("¿El paciente fuma? Inserte Si - No");
    fumador= scanner.nextLine();

    //Get Numero Historial Clinico
    System.out.println("Introduzca el número de historial clinico del              paciente");
    num_historial_clinico=scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine(); // consumir \s

    //Get Diagnostico
    System.out.println("Introduzca observaciones/comentarios/diagnóstico del paciente");
    Scanner sc_diagnostico = new Scanner(System.in);
    diagnostico= scanner.nextLine();

    Paciente.RegisterPaciente(nombre, apell1, apell2, edad, alcohol,  fumador, num_historial_clinico, diagnostico);
```